# Saving our own objects as keys in TreeMap

Tags: java

I was just wondering if there is any consideration to have in account when saving our own objects in a TreeMap. Something similar when we save our own objects as keys in a hashmap that we need to override equals and hashcode method to be able to retrieve them later. In a treemap there is no hash, a black red algorith is used, but I don't know if there is something special to do.
If so, could you tell me if there is something to have in account?

Thanks

Comment: Following on the point you already made, you have the option of specifying a custom comparator which can be used when elements need to be compared against each other when building/manipulating the tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc says:

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time

So you need to implement a natural ordering correctly, or implement a Comparator correctly.

It also says:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map, and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, must be consistent with equals if this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Map interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal. The behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Map interface.

So, if you want to obey the general contract of Map (and you should, generally), the compareTo() method must be consistent with equals(), which means that you need to correctly implement an equals() method, and transitively, a hashCode() method, and that you must make sure that `a.equals(b) iff e.compareTo(b) == 0`.

Most of the times, people screw up because they implement a compareTo/compare method that returns 0 for two objects, and still expect these two objects to be considered different by the map.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `equals` and `compareTo` transitivity there's one more thing that's terribly important.

- Your keys, or at least the fields you're using for comparison, should be **immutable**.

And you can actually use anything as a key for a TreeMap as long as you provide custom Comparator in its constructor.